# java, Morphia how to compare strings when using the Morphia Find Methods

Tags: java, morphia

Im new to this so here goes.
Trying to get a user called "Bob" from the MongoDb.

I have the:

```
UserData ud = MonConMan.instance().getDb().find(UserData.class, "name","bob").get();
```

The "bob" cannot be found if it has capital "Bob".
I understand i can get a `List` and do `equalsIgnoreCase` but are
there some Operators i can use?

I have users logging on and must test to see if they are registered. A user can type his name anyway he likes so must find a way to equalsIgnoreCase. Yea this is a problem, i    cannot get all names and do equalsIgnoreCase, if there are like 10,000. One could of course initially save all user names in lowercase but that would destroy the visual appearance of the name.

looking at the wiki but cannot see any..

http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up keeping two fields like
- lowercaseusername
- originalusername

This way i could search for a user using the lowercaseusername

Comment: Apparently this will also have the benefit that it will still hit the index, as opposed to the pattern matching method (via: http://goo.gl/O23WfY)

Answer (score 2):

Use java regex, like this.

```
String name = "bob";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^" + bob + "$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);//This line will create a pattern to match words starts with "b", ends with "b" and its case insensitive too.

Query<UserData> query = createQuery().field("name").equal(pattern).retrievedFields(true, "id");//Replace `id` with what ever name you use in UserData for '_id'
UserData user = query.get();
if(user!=null){
  //he is already registered
}
else{
//He is  a new guy

}
```

`(I am not good at regex, so you may have read about`$`&`^`somewhere. )`

You should be sure that the user names you are using to validate a new user should be unique across your system.

Answer (score 1):

You can make find a name of a `UserData` using this code :

```
Query<UserData> query = createQuery().filter("name","bob");
find(query);
```

In my application, this code return all `UserData` that haves a field `name` with "bob" value.
The code can be this way too :

```
Query<UserData> query = createQuery().field("name").equal("bob");
find(query);
```

These codes will be in a `UserDataDao` that extends `BasicDao`, and receives in the construtor the datastore from morphia.

Comment: But what if the name bob is spelled "BoB" , will it still return all?

Comment: can you use "contains" to bring all that haves a part of name. Example: field("name").contains("Bo"); But I don't know how he work with case Sensitive insertions.

Comment: I have users logging on and must test to see if they are registered.
A user can type his name anyway he likes so must find a way to equalsIgnoreCase. Yea this is a problem, i cannot get all names and do equalsIgnoreCase, if there are like 10,000